# Receiving "SSH tunnel creation failed: open failed" from datagrip when testing connection

Tags: windows, ssh, mysql, ssh-tunnel

When attempting to connect to a remote mysql server through an ssh tunnel using datagrip on windows 10 as the client, I receive "SSH Tunnel Creation failed: open failed".

I am able to establish and connect to the tunnel successfully with: `ssh username@mysqlServer -L 22:remoteHost:3306`.

I am using datagrip as the main demonstration of the problem, because it provides some debug information when testing the connection, but I have tried on dbeaver and tableplus, both failed to connect.

Other users in my organization are able to connect to the remote mysql server just fine on macos machines.

Logs from datagrip:

```
2022-04-18 14:58:14,313 [  57564]   INFO - n.s.s.t.r.JCERandom - Creating new SecureRandom.
2022-04-18 14:58:14,411 [  57662]   INFO - #c.i.s.i.s.sshj - Client identity string: SSH-2.0-IntelliJ__DataGrip_DB-221.5080.224__SSHJ_0.32.0_idea2
2022-04-18 14:58:14,508 [  57759]   INFO - #c.i.s.i.s.sshj - Server identity string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
2022-04-18 14:58:15,258 [  58509]   INFO - #c.i.s.i.s.sshj - Authentication log: SSH connection to username@mysqlServer:22
 * With altered connection settings:
  - authMethods: PublicKey(privateKeys=[C:\Users\spenc\.ssh\id_rsa, C:\Users\spenc\.ssh\id_dsa, C:\Users\spenc\.ssh\id_ecdsa, C:\Users\spenc\.ssh\id_ed25519, C:\Users\spenc\.ssh\id_xmss], agent=NO), Password, KeyboardInteractive
  - user: username
 * Connected: Socket[addr=mysqlServer/mysqlServer,port=22,localport=63766]
 * Starting authentication
  => none (failure, new auth methods allowed by the server: publickey)
  => publickey C:\Users\spenc\.ssh\id_rsa (success)
2022-04-18 14:58:15,270 [  58521]   INFO - #c.i.d.d.DatabaseSshTunnelEstablisher - SSH tunnel created: 63768:remoteHost:3306
2022-04-18 14:58:15,317 [  58568]   INFO - #c.i.e.r.RemoteProcessSupport - "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\DataGrip 2022.1.1\jbr\bin\java" -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Duser.timezone=UTC -Xmx750m -Xms128m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\DataGrip 2022.1.1\lib\util_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\DataGrip 2022.1.1\lib\util.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\DataGrip 2022.1.1\lib\groovy.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\DataGrip 2022.1.1\plugins\DatabaseTools\lib\jdbc-console.jar;C:\Users\spenc\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\DataGrip2022.1\jdbc-drivers\MySQL ConnectorJ\8.0.25\mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar" com.intellij.database.remote.RemoteJdbcServer com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
2022-04-18 14:58:15,705 [  58956]   INFO - #c.i.e.r.RemoteProcessSupport - Port/ServicesPort/ID: 58696/63770/RemoteDriverImpld6de775c
2022-04-18 14:58:15,713 [  58964]   INFO - #c.i.e.r.RemoteProcessSupport - 
2022-04-18 14:58:15,772 [  59023]   INFO - #c.i.d.d.DatabaseConnectionEstablisher - Connecting to: jdbc:mysql://remoteHost:3306/dbName
2022-04-18 14:58:15,774 [  59025]   INFO - #c.i.d.d.DatabaseConnectionEstablisher - Auth provider: user-pass
2022-04-18 14:58:15,776 [  59027]   INFO - #c.i.d.d.DatabaseCredentialsAuthProvider - Connecting as: username
2022-04-18 14:58:15,778 [  59029]   INFO - #c.i.d.d.DatabaseConnectionEstablisher - Connecting to (rewritten): jdbc:mysql://localhost:63768/dbName
2022-04-18 14:58:15,987 [  59238]   WARN - #c.i.s.i.s.sshj - <<chan#0 / open>> woke to: Opening `direct-tcpip` channel failed: open failed
2022-04-18 14:58:15,989 [  59240]   INFO - #c.i.s.i.s.sshj - Error in `SSHJ local tunnel for SshjSshConnection(username@mysqlServer)@82260ee: Local client /127.0.0.1:63774 ==> Local server localhost:63768 ==> Remote server remoteHost:3306`: net.schmizz.sshj.connection.channel.OpenFailException: open failed
2022-04-18 14:58:16,016 [  59267]   WARN - #c.i.d.d.BaseDatabaseErrorHandler$IOErrorInfo - Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.FullReadInputStream.readFully(FullReadInputStream.java:67)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:45)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:540)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readServerCapabilities(NativeProtocol.java:498)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.beforeHandshake(NativeProtocol.java:385)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1351)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:157)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:823)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:453)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.helpers.JdbcHelperImpl.connect(JdbcHelperImpl.java:639)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.helpers.MysqlBaseJdbcHelper.connect(MysqlBaseJdbcHelper.java:244)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.impl.RemoteDriverImpl.connect(RemoteDriverImpl.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Suppressed: com.intellij.database.util.AsyncTask$Frame$FrameData: Async frame data: Test Connection -> Prepare connection -> Establish database connection -> Get database credentials -> Perform database connection
2022-04-18 14:58:16,019 [  59270]   INFO - #c.i.e.r.RemoteProcessSupport - Terminating: 127.0.0.1:58696/RemoteDriverImpld6de775c
2022-04-18 14:58:16,054 [  59305]   INFO - #c.i.e.r.RemoteProcessSupport - Process finished with exit code -1
```

---

Update: I tried "MySQL Workbench" for Windows and that mysteriously worked immediately. I tried the other clients once more and none of them successfully connected. I'm not adding this as an answer since it's just a workaround and doesn't solve nor illuminate the original problem.